# Strange behavior in shiny RMarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm having some very strange behavior when knitting a shiny RMarkdown HTML document. In the MWE below I simply (1) include a slider input, (2) include a column in the df as the value of the input and then (3) return the df. The MWE below returns the error `Error in : Column "b" must be length 1 (the number of rows), not 0`. If I take out the multiplication of the input value when I assign a value to b, the document knits with no problem. MWE:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

Testing

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
# Input slider
sliderInput("test", "Test", value = 0.5, min = 0, max = 1, width = "100%")

# Pre-define df
output <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(a = 20))

observe({

  output$data <- output$data %>%
    # Manipulate df
    mutate(b = input$test * 2)

})

# Return df
renderDataTable({output$data})

```
````

Does anyone know what could be causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I suspect is going on ---

I think that the first time your `observe` is run through, that `input$test` is NULL.

If your `mutate` sets a column to NULL, it would just remove that column.

If you use `input$test * 2` that will return an empty vector `numeric(0)`. Trying to add a column with an empty vector would give the error.

If you add `req(input$test)` at the beginning of your `observe` function, does it work?